# Problem with bibliography (latin1) - how to find the exact place

Tags: bibliographies, errors

I've got a problem with my bibliography. After running my tex-file I get the error messages:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `latin1'.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.285           \printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]

You need to provide a definition with \DeclareInputText 
or \DeclareInputMath before using this key.
```

I had a look at my bib-files and retyped every special character like "-" or "ä/ö/ü". How can I see in which entry the problem occurs exactly?

Greetings, Daniela

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Divide and conquer: halve the `bib` file and try to see what half causes the problem; then repeat until the faulty entry is isolated. Then, either you see what's causing the problem or you can present it here.

Comment: are you sure your bib file (or the generated bibliography) aren't in utf8 rather than latin1?

Answer (score 4):

I would suspect that your bibliography is in UTF-8 rather than latin1, but one way to see what is causing the error is to redefine the command that makes the error.

This document has a control character (129) between `aaa` and `bbb`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

aaaa  bbbb

\end{document}
```

and normally makes

```
! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `latin1'.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.10 aaaa �
            bbbb
? x
```

But if you would rather see something in the document then you can add

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand\PackageError[3]{[[[ERROR FOR PACKAGE #1]]]}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

aaaa  bbbb

\end{document}
```

Now the document runs without error and the typeset result is:

[image]

Giving a visual indication of the location of the error in the document.